# pandas data frame, select most common value from all rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame and I'd like to take from one Col1 the one most frequent colour. There are a few types of colours: Green, Yellow, Blue, Black.

Col1 has a lot of data. Random colours. For example:

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: lts a dupe, look into value_counts()

Comment: Ok I have 
pd.value_counts(df['colours'].values, sort=True)

But there are more than one records. I want to see the only one record from this code. 

How can I do this?

Comment: df['colours'].value_counts()[0] will do. Default is sort = True so that parameter is not needed

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `mode` , data from MissBleu

```
df.colors.mode()
Out[36]: 
0     Green
1    Yellow
dtype: object
```

The reason why you have two rather than one : Both of them have frequency 4

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the solution

```
pd.value_counts(df['colours'].values, sort=True).head(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like

```
import pandas as pd
colordf = { 'colors' : ['Green', 'Yellow', 'Blue', 'Orange', 'Green',
          'Yellow', 'Blue', 'Orange', 'Green', 'Yellow'],
            'numbers' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,8]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(colordf)
df['colors'].value_counts().head(1)
```